# PHP Inheritance not passing values

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out to pass values from a parent class, I've tried to replicate the most basic examples but cannot get it to work.
Please help.

```
class mother
{
    public function __construct($db=""){
        $this -> db = $db; 
    }
     
    public function setValue($name,$value){
        $this -> $name = $value;
    }

    public function getValue($name){
        return $this -> $name;
    }
}

class son extends mother
{
    
    function __construct(){
        
    }

    public function show_name(){
        return $this->name;
    }
}

$a = new mother($db);
$a->setValue("name", 'Usman');

$b = new son();
$name = $b->show_name();
```

The parent class (mother) will have values set using the setValue function, should I not be able to access those values from the son class?

Comment: I think you need $b->setValue('name','someValue');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$a` is just an object of class Mother, `$b` just an object of class Son. There is no link Automatically between the property values of these 2 objects.

If you want to use the `$b` the Son class you will have to load data into it first

So when you create a Son object you get the functionality of Mother as well i.e. Methods and properties, but not the values you placed in Mother before creating Son. They are seperate.

```
class mother
{
    public $name;
    public function __construct($db=""){
        $this -> db = $db; 
    }
     
    public function setValue($name,$value){
        $this->{$name} = $value;
    }

    public function getValue($name){
        return $this -> $name;
    }
}

class son extends mother
{
    

}

$db = 1;   # just to make it work
$a = new mother($db);
$a->setValue("name", 'Usman');

$b = new son();
# note calling the Mother method from the Son class
$b->setValue("name", 'Riggs');

#note, calling methods that only exists in Mother
echo $a->getValue('name');
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $b->getValue('name');
```

RESULT

```
Usman
Riggs
```

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly, I'd assumed values were also inherited.

Answer (score 0):

You have created two separate objects `$a` and `$b`. If you set something in an object `$a` it is not visible both `$b`. You should do the setting of the value in the `$b` object not in `$a`.

Another thing is the correct construction of the `son` object, despite the inheritance from the `mother` class, you do not set the value of `$db` in it. Modify your `son` class to take this value in the constructor and pass it to the `mother` class constructor , or remove the empty constructor of the `son` class and use that from the `mother` class.

```
class son extends mother
{   
    public function show_name()
    {
        // You are building a lot of dynamic fields, 
        //so if you use a table, you can check a collection of their names.
        //I explain the use of the table below in the mother class code. 
        return array_keys($this->fields); 
    }
}

$b = new son($db); //here you are using a mother constructor
$b->setValue("name", 'Usman');
$b->setValue("name1", 'Usman1');
$b->setValue("name2", 'Usman2');
$name = $b->show_name(); //$name is an array of names here
```

It's also good practice to explicitly declare fields in classes and not create everything with public access (like `$db` in example below). Regarding dynamic fields, in my opinion, it would also be much better to build them as a table.

```
class mother
{
    protected $db;
    protected $fields;

    public function __construct($db="")
    {
        $this->db = $db; 
        $this->fields = [];
    }
 
    public function setValue($name, $value)
    {
        $this->fields[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function getValue($name)
    {
       return $this->fields[$name] ?? null; //if the value of name does not exist, we will return anything, e.g. null
    }
}
```

If you execute code with `var_dump($name);` you will see

> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "name" [1]=> string(5) "name1" [2]=>
> string(5) "name2" }